# Change url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

All url on my website have url:

```
www.domain.com/name+name+name+name
```

How change all url to:

```
www.domain.com/name-name-name-name
```

my htaccess is like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|tpl)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.* /index.php [L]
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Do you want to change `+` to `-`?

Comment: You don’t “change the URL” in ‘.htaccess‘. You need to *change* the URL in your application - have you done that already? In ‘.htaccess‘ you could then issue a *redirect* to preserve SEO. Is it this *redirect* that you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes i want change + to -

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to *redirect* all the old URLs that contain `+` (plus) to the new URLs that contain `-` (hyphen) instead (ie. replace `+` with `-`) then you can do something like the following in `.htaccess` before your existing mod_rewrite directives:

```
# Replace all "+" with "-" with repeating "internal rewrite" and set env var "REPLACED"
RewriteRule (.*)\+(.*) $1-$2 [N,E=REPLACED:1]

# If env var "REPLACED" is set then issue final "external redirect" to the new URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REPLACED} .
RewriteRule (.+) /$1 [R,L]
```

Clarification... this isn't strictly "changing the URL with `.htaccess`". The above assumes the URL has already been "changed in your application" (to use hyphens instead of pluses) and the redirect above is to benefit SEO where the old URL (that contained pluses) has been indexed, linked to and bookmarked.